# Prove countability of letter combinations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

A sentence written in 'Fakelang' is made up of letters from a finite set X. These letters follow certain syntax rules. The task is to prove that the number of sentences possible in Fakelang is countable. How do you prove this?

My thinking: X is countable. A sentence made up of letters from X will be countable. No matter how long the sentence is, as long as it is finite in length, the possible combinations will also be finite (combinations will necessarily be less than $|X|^n$ due to the syntax rules). Since each subset of 'total combinations' is countable and finite, the 'total combinations' set must also be countable.

Is my thinking wrong? What is lacking for this to be considered a proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track.

A bit more formal:

Let $X$, the set of  letters, be finite.

Now consider a sentence of length $n$, i.e.

$n$ spaces.

Let $P_n$ be the set of all permutations of length $n$ with elements (letters , spaces , and what not) in $X$. $P_n$ is finite.

Consider the set $P$:

$P:= \displaystyle{ \cup}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} P_n$.

$P$ as the countable union of countable (actually finite) sets is countable.

Let $S$ be the set of sentences in Fakelang of finite length, then

$S \subset P$, hence countable .

Comment: Thanks a lot! Additional question: if the sentence has to be of finite length, will the number of possible sentences still be infinite? Considering the fact that your can always construct a sentence longer the previous one?

Comment: Adam.A pleasure.We are considering sentences of length, say n= 10,100, 1000,... etc.Every sentence has length n(finite).Then S is countable infinite.Is this your question?

Comment: Yes, that was the question. Thanks again!